# SendMailAsync : An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task-parallel-library, smtpclient

While using `SendMailAsync` I am getting the following error:

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending

My code :

```
public static async Task SendEmail(MessageContent messageContent, string emailBody)
{
   SmtpClient smtpClientNoSend = new SmtpClient();
   await smtpClientNoSend.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
}
```

Call From Controller:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Register()
{
   await SendEmail();
}

private void SendEmail()
{
  SMTPEmail.SendEmail(msg, output.ToString());
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your call hierarchy is broken. You shouldn't use `async void`, that is ment for event handlers only, use `async Task` instead:

```
public static Task SendEmailAsync(MessageContent messageContent, string emailBody)
{
   SmtpClient smtpClientNoSend = new SmtpClient();
   return smtpClientNoSend.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Register()
{
   await SendEmailAsync();
}

private Task SendEmailAsync()
{
   return SMTPEmail.SendEmailAsync(msg, output.ToString());
}
```

Side note - I'm not sure why you have so many `SendMail` methods, You could narrow them down to a single method call.

Comment: I don't understand the `Register()` method. Should it not include a `return` statement?

Comment: @RaelB No, it's a `Task` returning method. It is equivalent to returning `void` from a synchronous method.